# Jenkins+Nexus - Parsing POM fails with Peer Not Authenticated

Tags: ssh, jenkins, nexus

Not a duplicate! I've reviewed the SO resources with similar titles, but this problem seems to be related to Jenkins and ssh, and the others don't cover this problem. Specifically, this is not a maven problem it's a Jenkins problem.

When parsing my POM, Jenkins fails to connect to nexus through ssh (It's looking for the parent POM to the one it's processing). At this point in the process (near the start), the POM isn't being read by maven itself -- it's being used by Jenkins (or one of it's plugins) to create a dependency tree so that projects can be built in the correct order. The error I'm getting is `peer not authenticated`.

Here's the relevant bit of the output:

```
Parsing POMs
Failed to transfer Could not transfer metadata org.us.thing:thingy:2.0/maven-metadata.xml 
from/to nexus (https://nexus:2443/nexus/content/groups/public):
peer not authenticated

ERROR: Processing failed due to a bug in the code. Please report this to jenkinsci-users@googlegroups.com
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to build parent project for org.us.thing:thingy:pom:2.0
    at org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.getParent(MavenProject.java:381)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1325)
```

I have configured a trust store using `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`, and this works fine, through Jenkins, when maven is running a build. I also think that Jenkins is paying attention to it somehow because the error one gets when not using the trust store is usually different, but I'm not sure if this is really true.

I have configured an artifact resolver as a repo manager with my nexus url and credentials. I have also set up a 'Credentails' entry for the nexus domain also with my credentials.

So, how to proceed? I solution would be nice, but I'll settle for more breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Jenkins is failing to connect to Nexus before parsing the POM, that means the information set in the POM doesn't provide enough info to connect. The credentials entry is a good first step.

Jenkins provides an option to set this information earlier. The [config file provider](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) plugin, allows you to set up an "external" file. This lets you set up both a global and a user Maven `settings.xml`. Then in your build configuration, you can add a build step to use that managed file. I find it helpful to set up two things:

1. A Jenkins build step to use a managed file for the global config
2. A managed file for the user config in the advanced settings of the Maven step itself.

This externalizes all the connection information from the POM and gets rid of the timing order problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could also be a bug in the [Maven Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) . This plugin tries to parse the `pom.xml` in the build step before your maven job is run. However the plugin might not use your configured settings.xml or your maven goals and options correctly (in my case it ignored `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true` `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true`).

A workaround is to configure a pre build step for your project in Jenkins like Pre-Step->Invoke top level Maven target->Goal: `clean -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true`. This pre build step will download necessary dependencies, so that the maven project plugin can find them in the build step and can parse the pom successfully.